# how to find adjoint of this operator on the space of C[0,1]?

Tags: adjoint-operators

We are given $T$ is an operator on $C[0,1]$ as follows

$T(g(x))=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}p_kg(f_k(x)), p_k\in [0,1], f_k\in C[0,1]$, could anyone tell me how to show adjoint of this operator is as follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual of $C[0,1]$ is the space of all signed/complex measures on $[0,1]$ with total variation norm. we have $T^{*}(\mu)(g)=\mu (Tg)=\int Tg d\mu=\int \sum p_kg(f_k)d\mu=\sum p_k \int gd(\mu\circ f_k^{-1})$ and hence $T^{*}=\sum p_k \mu\circ f_k^{-1}$

Comment: So, on which object $T^*$ will act? I am not understanding that. will it act on some subset of $[0,1]$ or the space I am considering and give me a measure of that subset or it will give me a new measure?

Comment: $T:C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ so $T^{*}:(C([0,1])^{*} \to C([0,1])^{*}$. $C([0,1])^{*}$ ois the space of measures on Borel subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Then why did you write $T^*(\mu)(g)$? Would it be $T^*(\mu)(A)$? where $A$ is some Borel subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: When you think of the dual of $C[0,1]$ as the space of measures you make an identification:  a measure $\mu$ is also regarded as a continuous linear functional on $C[0,1]$ defined by $\mu (f)=\int_0^{1}f d\mu$.

Comment: Okay! so $T^*: (C[0,1])^*\to (C[0,1])^*, T^*(\mu)(g)= \mu(Tg)$ Thanks!!! I Love you!

Comment: Another obscurity: why or how this $f_k^{-1}$ thing is appearing in the definition of $T^*$?

Comment: @DingDong $\int g(f) d\mu=\int g d(\mu\circ f^{-1})$. This is the change of variables formula.